# Why is JSONObject un-ordered? What is the reason behind this?

Tags: java, json

I want to understand the reason and/or core-logic for JSONObject is being an un-ordered set. Because in most of my cases there would be a request which needs response as a JSONObject in the order of time/position. After searching, I found lot of members telling to use JSONArray which I do not feel a good solution.

I want to get a clear idea before proceeding further.

Thank you in advance.

Comment: Why is JSONArray not a good idea?

Comment: Objects dont have any order for the parameters, if you have a list of items then this needs to be done in an array.

Comment: A JSONObject is not an unordered set.  It's more like a HashMap than anything else.  The only thing that has order in JSON are arrays

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`JSONObject` is unordered because objects described by [JSON](http://json.org) are unordered, by specification:

> An object is an unordered set of name/value pairs.

(Which is because JSON is derived from [is a subset of] JavaScript's [object initializer syntax](http://ecma-international.org/ecma-262/5.1/#sec-11.1.5), and JavaScript objects are unordered — because there's no reason for the properties of an object to be ordered in the general case. That can be left to specializations of objects, like JavaScript's arrays, which are [nothing more than objects](http://blog.niftysnippets.org/2011/01/myth-of-arrays.html) with some special handling of property names, and associated array-like functions.)

Answer (score 0):

The true, complete reason is only known by the members of the ECMA committee which finalized the ECMAScript specification since JSONObjects are a subset of JavaScript Objects; however, here is my guess.

To require that the properties of a JSON Object maintain a fixed order would likely add additional implementation overhead to a data structure which would otherwise be simpler without having that requirement.  For example, a JSON object could be implemented as a simple hashtable; however, if the order of the properties was to remain fixed then an additional data structure would be required to list their order.

Comment: ECMA didn't specify JSON (at least not directly), as far as I know.

Comment: @JoachimSauer: sure, but since JSON is the "JavaScript Object Notation" you can still think of the ECMAScript spec as having considerable impact on JSON.

Answer (score 0):

If JavaScript prescribed ordering of object properties, it would preclude the usage of hashtables in their implementation. On the other hand, why would an object's properties be ordered in the first place? It seems like an arbitrary constraint with, as we can see, far-reaching negative consequences.